# Given a string in Java, just take the first X letters

Tags: java, string

Is there something like a C# Substring for Java? I'm creating a mobile application for Blackberry device and due to screen constraints I can only afford to show 13 letters plus three dots for an ellipsis.

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this?

I need bare bones Java and not some fancy trick because I doubt a mobile device has access to a complete framework. At least in my experience working with Java ME a year ago.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/. You should find the docs for whatever framework is installed on your platform, and have that handy.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can do exactly what you want with `String.substring()`.

```
String str = "please truncate me after 13 characters!";
if (str.length() > 16)
    str = str.substring(0, 13) + "..."
```

Comment: you mena if (str.length() > 13) right? In ay way what if str.length is 14, wont you have an index out of bound? :P

Comment: @Paolo i dont see there mistake. He is taking substring in length of 13 and adding extra 3 chars. If string is longer than 16 chars, he makes it 16 chars long. In my opinion there is no problem.

Answer (score 39):

```
String foo = someString.substring(0, Math.min(13, someString.length()));
```

---

**Edit:** Just for general reference, as of Guava 16.0 you can do:

```
String truncated = Ascii.truncate(string, 16, "...");
```

to truncate at a max length of 16 characters with an ellipsis.

**Aside**

Note, though, that truncating a string for display by character isn't a good  system for anything where i18n might need to be considered. There are (at least) a few different issues with it:

1. You may want to take word boundaries and/or whitespace into account to avoid truncating at an awkward place.
2. Splitting surrogate pairs (though this can be avoided just by checking if the character you want to truncate at is the first of a surrogate pair).
3. Splitting a character and a combining character that follows it (e.g. an `e` followed by a combining character that puts an accent on that `e`.)
4. The appearance of a character may change depending on the character that follows it in certain languages, so just truncating at that character will produce something that doesn't even look like the original.

For these reasons (and others), my understanding is that best practice for truncation for display in a UI is to actually fade out the rendering of the text at the correct point on the screen rather than truncating the underlying string.

Comment: Yeah that worked great. Thanks a bunch! :) Getting an indexOutOfBounds exception even though I know what Math.min does and it should work... let me check this out with the debugger.

Comment: @Colin, with this logic, you don't know if you need ellipses.

Comment: @Justin: True... I was just giving a quick example of getting a substring with the first X letters. Your example is certainly more applicable to his specific situation.

Comment: @Colin, I'm just being uber competitive, sorry.  Your answer is just fine.

Comment: @Justin "I'm just being uber competitive" says the guy with the 23.2K rep :-) LOL

Comment: @Bert, I cant't help it.  StackOverflow is the biggest game/competition to me.  Whenever I answer a question I **have** to \*win\*.

Comment: @Justin: I think Bert's point is that your score is awfully low (given you've been on the site for two years now) for someone who's as competitive as you say you are. :-P (Mine is nothing grand either, but then again I'm not very active on this site any more.)

Comment: @Chris, Haha, yeah.  I need to try harder!!  I guess I'm a quality over quantity guy.  If I provide an answer...it better be the best.  (Wow, #13, you are an old member.)

Comment: @Justin agreed - StackOverflow has a lot of parallels to MMORPGs for me (rep == exp, questions == quests, etc).  SO is my other WoW. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Whenever there is some operation that you would think is a very common thing to do, yet the Java API requires you to check bounds, catch exceptions, use `Math.min()`, etc. (i.e. requires more work than you would expect), check Apache's [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). It's almost always there in a more concise format. In this case, you would use `StringUtils#substring` which does the error case handling for you. Here's what it's javadoc says:

```
Gets a substring from the specified String avoiding exceptions.

A negative start position can be used to start n characters from the end of the String.

A null String will return null. An empty ("") String will return "".

 StringUtils.substring(null, *)   = null
 StringUtils.substring("", *)     = ""
 StringUtils.substring("abc", 0)  = "abc"
 StringUtils.substring("abc", 2)  = "c"
 StringUtils.substring("abc", 4)  = ""
 StringUtils.substring("abc", -2) = "bc"
 StringUtils.substring("abc", -4) = "abc"
```

Comment: "I need bare bones Java and not some fancy trick because I doubt a mobile device has access to a complete framework ..."

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "This is Mobile application."
System.out.println(str.subSequence(0, 13)+"...");
```

Comment: So this solution also throws an index out of bounds for short strings