# Get one letter abbreviation of week day of a date in java

Tags: java, android, date, format

As far I know, in Java I can get weekdays in normal (Friday) or short mode (Fri). But, there is any way to obtain only first letter?

I thought I can get first letter using "substring", but it won't be correct for all languages. For example, spanish weekdays are: Lunes, Martes, Miércoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sábado and Domingo, and first letter for "Miércoles" is X instead of M to difference it from "Martes".

Comment: Hmm, French and Italian both have the same problems, but I have never seen single letter abbreviations used in any of these two languages. Heck, even _English_ has this problem.

Comment: Two ways using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html): (1) `LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEEE"))` (substitute any date or date-time object instead of `LocalDate.now()`) (2) `LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW, Locale.ENGLISH)` (substitute any `DayOfWeek` object instead of `LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek()`). Both will typically print one letter. If for older Android use java.time through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Android you can use SimpleDateFormat with "EEEEE". In the next example you can see it.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatLetterDay = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE",Locale.getDefault());
String letter = formatLetterDay.format(new Date());
```

---

EDIT: it's actually not entirely true. The result on Android could have more than a single letter (and also non-unique, if this matters), but this is what we have. Here's proof that you won't get these characteristics on Android, going over all locales. It's written in Kotlin, but should work for Java too, of course:

```
val charCountStats = SparseIntArray()
Locale.getAvailableLocales().forEach { locale ->
    val sb = StringBuilder("$locale : ")
    val formatLetterDay = SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE", locale)
    for (day in 1..7) {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day)
        val letter: String = formatLetterDay.format(cal.time)
        charCountStats.put(letter.length, charCountStats.get(letter.length, 0)+1)
        sb.append(letter)
        if (day != 7)
            sb.append(',')
    }
    Log.d("AppLog", "$sb")
}
Log.d("AppLog", "stats:")
charCountStats.forEach { key, value ->
    Log.d("AppLog", "formatted days with $key characters:$value")
}
```

And the result is that for most cases it's indeed a single letter, but for many it's more, and can even reaches 8 characters (though it might look as less letters, even one) :

```
formatted days with 1 characters:4889
formatted days with 2 characters:471
formatted days with 3 characters:99
formatted days with 4 characters:58
formatted days with 5 characters:3
formatted days with 8 characters:3
```

Example of a locale that it shows as 3 letters (and not just has 3 letters) is "wo" ("Wolof" language), as this is the result for each of its days of the week using the above formatting:

```
Dib,Alt,Tal,Àla,Alx,Àjj,Ase
```

Comment: This does not work on API 16, it returns the full day name. In API 18 and above seem to work fine.

Comment: For API 16 or older, `DateUtils.getDayOfWeekString(dayOfWeek, DateUtils.LENGTH_SHORTEST)`

Comment: How come it's not written here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - See my answer.

Comment: @StephenC Indeed, I've updated the above answer with proof that it's not a single letter for all languages.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above there is no standard Java support for this. Using the formatting string "EEEEE" however is not guaranteed to work on all Android devices. The following code is guaranteed to work on any device:

```java
public String firstLetterOfDayOfTheWeek(Date date) {

    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault(); 
    DateFormat weekdayNameFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", locale); 
    String weekday = weekdayNameFormat.format(date); 
    return weekday.charAt(0)+""; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard Java API support for doing that<sup>1</sup>.

Part of the reason is that many (maybe even most) languages don't have conventional unique one-letter weekday abbreviations.  In English there isn't, for example (M T W T F S S).

A (hypothetical) formatting option that doesn't work<sup>2</sup> in many / most locales would be an impediment to internationalization rather than a help.

---

It has been pointed out that:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatLetterDay = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE", Locale.getDefault());
String letter = formatLetterDay.format(new Date());
```

gives one letter abbreviations for later versions of Android (18 and above), though the [javadocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) do not mention this.  It appears that this "5 letter" format has been borrowed from `DateTimeFormatter` whose [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter) says:

> The count of pattern letters determines the format.
>
> Text: The text style is determined based on the number of pattern letters used. Less than 4 pattern letters will use the short form. Exactly 4 pattern letters will use the full form. **Exactly 5 pattern letters will use the narrow form.** ...

If you are targeting Android API 26 or later, you should consider using the `java.time.*` classes rather than the legacy classes.

But either way, this isn't guaranteed to give you *unique* day letters.

---

<sup>1 - By "that" I mean mapping to *unique* 1-letter abbreviations.

2 - I mean it doesn't work in the human sense.  You could invent a convention, but typical people wouldn't understand what the abbreviations meant; e.g. they wouldn't know that "X" meant "Miércoles", or in English that (say) "R" meant "Thursday" (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21049169/139985).</sup>

Comment: 1. The "EEEEE" is known to be supported on Java. Example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html . As for characteristics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html#NARROW  . 2. What do you mean to use "java.time.*", if SimpleDateFormat is already from there? 3. For some reason you've written your example only in English, so I've added a simple test for all supported locales of the device, to show how it's formatted for each. Indeed in various languages it's more than 1 letter, and in many it's not unique.

Comment: 2.  Because `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` are all legacy classes with various API problems.  They have been superseded.  3.  My example is not English-centric.  It is you who is making the assumption that the default locale is English.  Not me.  4. Feel free to write your own answer ... rather than putting words into my mouth.

Comment: 2. Right, but they are widely used in various situations (and are supported), including places that are not setting them as deprecated, such as formatting, no? 3. Right, but emulator by default is in English, and using `Locale.getDefault()` isn't specific and might not show your point, so that's what I could use. 4. Sorry for that. I didn't mean to upset you. I just thought it would be better to prove your point by showing it on all locales. Not one that might not show your point at all (some locales might have the format produce unique, single letter string for each day).

Answer (score 1):

I realize the OP was asking for standards across languages, and this does not address it.  But there is/was a standard for using single character Day of Week abbreviation.

Back in mainframe days, using a 1-character abbreviation for Day of Week was common, either to store day of week in 1 character field (to save precious space), or have a report heading for single-character column.  The "standard" was to use MTWRFSU, where R was for Thursday, and U for Sunday.

I could not find any definitive references to this (which is why I quoted "standard", but here are a couple of examples:
http://eventguide.com/topics/one_digit_day_abbreviations.html
http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/soc/definitions.htm#Anchor-Days-3800

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no direct java function to get the first letter and no standard way to do it.

You can refer to this link to obtain the first letter of the string day using substring() java method

[Given a string in Java, just take the first X letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878222/given-a-string-in-java-just-take-the-first-x-letters)

Comment: I don't know if getting first letter will be correct for all lanugages, because the problem described.

Comment: I guess you can  do a mapping own your own based on the language ie. Miércoles" is X ,instead of X display M .But it will not be feasible if you want to support large no. of languages .It

Comment: I want to support all languages :)

Answer (score 0):

`DateFormatSymbols.getWeekdays` with a width of `NARROW` will give you the first letter of each week day. It works for every language. However, it requires API 24.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    String[] weekDays = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
            .getWeekdays(DateFormatSymbols.STANDALONE, DateFormatSymbols.NARROW);
}
```