# unable to use coordinator layout along with constraint layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have an android project which uses coordinator layout to design one layout. it worked fine until I added `'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'` to the dependencies.

when ever I open that particular layout using coordinator layout on my marshmello device, it throws an runtime exception.

```
03-17 11:39:30.247 10261-10261/com.alamkanak.weekview D/AndroidRuntime:     Shutting down VM
03-17 11:39:30.250 10261-10261/com.alamkanak.weekview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.alamkanak.weekview, PID: 10261
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alamkanak.weekview/com.alamkanak.weekview.sample.BasicActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2445)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                        at com.alamkanak.weekview.sample.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:49)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                        at com.alamkanak.weekview.sample.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:49) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                        at com.alamkanak.weekview.sample.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:49) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:185)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:179)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                        at com.alamkanak.weekview.sample.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:49) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
03-17 11:39:30.254 10261-10261/com.alamkanak.weekview E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
03-17 11:39:30.286 10261-10261/com.alamkanak.weekview I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10261 SIG: 9
```

help me to get rid of this exception.

activity_base.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseActivity"
    android:background="#fff">

    <com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView
        android:id="@+id/weekView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:eventTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:textSize="12sp"
        app:hourHeight="60dp"
        app:headerColumnPadding="8dp"
        app:headerColumnTextColor="@color/toolbar_text"
        app:headerRowPadding="12dp"
        app:columnGap="8dp"
        app:noOfVisibleDays="3"
        app:headerRowBackgroundColor="@color/toolbar"
        app:dayBackgroundColor="#05000000"
        app:todayBackgroundColor="#1848adff"
        app:headerColumnBackground="#ffffffff"
        app:todayHeaderTextColor="@color/accent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

BaseActivity.java

```
package com.alamkanak.weekview.sample;

import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.alamkanak.weekview.DateTimeInterpreter;
import com.alamkanak.weekview.MonthLoader;
import com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView;
import com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekViewEvent;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * This is a base activity which contains week view and all the codes necessary to initialize the
 * week view.
 * Created by Raquib-ul-Alam Kanak on 1/3/2014.
 * Website: http://alamkanak.github.io
 */
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WeekView.EventClickListener, MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener, WeekView.EventLongPressListener, WeekView.EmptyViewLongPressListener {
    private static final int TYPE_DAY_VIEW = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_WEEK_VIEW = 3;
    private int mWeekViewType = TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW;
    private static WeekView mWeekView;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        // Get a reference for the week view in the layout.
        mWeekView = (WeekView) findViewById(R.id.weekView);

        // Show a toast message about the touched event.
        mWeekView.setOnEventClickListener(this);

        // The week view has infinite scrolling horizontally. We have to provide the events of a
        // month every time the month changes on the week view.
        mWeekView.setMonthChangeListener(this);

        // Set long press listener for events.
        mWeekView.setEventLongPressListener(this);

        // Set long press listener for empty view
        mWeekView.setEmptyViewLongPressListener(this);

        // Set up a date time interpreter to interpret how the date and time will be formatted in
        // the week view. This is optional.
        setupDateTimeInterpreter(false);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                showPopup(view);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        setupDateTimeInterpreter(id == R.id.action_week_view);
        switch (id){
            case R.id.action_today:
                mWeekView.goToToday();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_day_view:
                if (mWeekViewType != TYPE_DAY_VIEW) {
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    mWeekViewType = TYPE_DAY_VIEW;
                    mWeekView.setNumberOfVisibleDays(1);

                    // Lets change some dimensions to best fit the view.
                    mWeekView.setColumnGap((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setEventTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.action_three_day_view:
                if (mWeekViewType != TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW) {
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    mWeekViewType = TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW;
                    mWeekView.setNumberOfVisibleDays(3);

                    // Lets change some dimensions to best fit the view.
                    mWeekView.setColumnGap((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setEventTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.action_week_view:
                if (mWeekViewType != TYPE_WEEK_VIEW) {
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    mWeekViewType = TYPE_WEEK_VIEW;
                    mWeekView.setNumberOfVisibleDays(7);

                    // Lets change some dimensions to best fit the view.
                    mWeekView.setColumnGap((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setEventTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                }
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Set up a date time interpreter which will show short date values when in week view and long
     * date values otherwise.
     * @param shortDate True if the date values should be short.
     */
    private void setupDateTimeInterpreter(final boolean shortDate) {
        mWeekView.setDateTimeInterpreter(new DateTimeInterpreter() {
            @Override
            public String interpretDate(Calendar date) {
                SimpleDateFormat weekdayNameFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.getDefault());
                String weekday = weekdayNameFormat.format(date.getTime());
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" M/d", Locale.getDefault());

                // All android api level do not have a standard way of getting the first letter of
                // the week day name. Hence we get the first char programmatically.
                // Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959502/get-one-letter-abbreviation-of-week-day-of-a-date-in-java#answer-16959657
                if (shortDate)
                    weekday = String.valueOf(weekday.charAt(0));
                return weekday.toUpperCase() + format.format(date.getTime());
            }

            @Override
            public String interpretTime(int hour) {
                return hour > 11 ? (hour - 12) + " PM" : (hour == 0 ? "12 AM" : hour + " AM");
            }
        });
    }

    protected String getEventTitle(Calendar time) {
        return String.format("Event of %02d:%02d %s/%d", time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), time.get(Calendar.MINUTE), time.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventClick(WeekViewEvent event, RectF eventRect) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked " + event.getName() + ", Id : " + event.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventLongPress(WeekViewEvent event, RectF eventRect) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Long pressed event: " + event.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmptyViewLongPress(Calendar time) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Empty view long pressed: " + getEventTitle(time), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static WeekView getWeekView() {
        return mWeekView;
    }

    public void showPopup(View anchorView) {

/*        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        // MainActivity2.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View popupWindow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_event,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.createEventPopup));
        final PopupWindow fadePopup = new PopupWindow(popupWindow, screenWidth, screenHeight, false);
        fadePopup.showAtLocation(popupWindow, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);

        final Button cancel = (Button) popupWindow.findViewById(R.id.CE_button_cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fadePopup.dismiss();
            }
        });

        fadePopup.setFocusable(true);
        fadePopup.update();
*/

    }



}
```

these are all the libraries I have added.

```
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'


  compile files('src/main/java/com/alamkanak/weekview/sample/volley.jar')
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching your appcompat and design libraries to current version 25.3.0

replace this part:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
```

with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
```

in your app's gradle file.