# events not showing while using a library

Tags: android

I am using a library for calendar called "alamkanak weekview" and I tried to add an sqLite data base where I can add and delete the events and so i did make them the delete and adding to the data base works just fine but the showing of events is all once it shows no event after i add and once it show one but repeated the time that is the size of the elements in the table , i tried to fix this but couldn't because i lack experience in android

here's the class where i add my class that adds the events from the data base

```java
public class BasicActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public db_cal db;


    public int newYear;
    public int newMonth;


    // public int idd = 0
    // ;
    private List<WeekViewEvent> getEventsForMonth(int year, int month) {
        List<WeekViewEvent> tempList = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();


        Calendar tmpen=Calendar.getInstance();
        db = new db_cal(getApplicationContext());
        // Populate the week view with some events.
        List<WeekViewEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
        List<events> evenement = db.getAllEvenement();

        WeekViewEvent event= new WeekViewEvent();
        events tmp;
        for(events vent : evenement) {
            Log.d("taille1", evenement.size() + "");
           // tmp = vent.;
            //event = new WeekViewEvent(tmp.getId(), tmp.getName(),tmp.getStart(), tmp.getEnd());
            event.setId(vent.getId());
            event.setName(vent.getName());
            event.setStartTime(vent.getStart());
            event.setEndTime(vent.getEnd());
            //idd=idd+1;
            Log.d("nom", vent.getName() + "");
            event.setColor(getResources().getColor(randcol()));
            events.add(event);
        }
        for (WeekViewEvent weekViewEvent : events) {
            if ((weekViewEvent.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MONTH))+1 == month && weekViewEvent.getStartTime().get(Calendar.YEAR) ==
                    year) {
                tempList.add(weekViewEvent);
            }
        }

        return tempList;
    }
    public List<? extends WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
        int month = newMonth;
        return getEventsForMonth(newYear,month);// I tried to use newMonth-1 directly here but it dosen't work i don't know why but it doesn't matter
    }


  /*  @Override
    public List<? extends WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
        this.newYear = newYear;
        this.newMonth = newMonth;
      /*  Calendar tmpdb=Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar tmpen=Calendar.getInstance();
        db = new db_cal(getApplicationContext());
        // Populate the week view with some events.
        List<WeekViewEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
        List<events> evenement = db.getAllEvenement();

        WeekViewEvent event= new WeekViewEvent();
        events tmp;
        for(int i=0;i<evenement.size();i++) {
            Log.d("taille1",evenement.size()+"");
            tmp=evenement.get(i);
            //event = new WeekViewEvent(tmp.getId(), tmp.getName(),tmp.getStart(), tmp.getEnd());
            event.setId(i);
            event.setName(tmp.getName());
            event.setStartTime(tmp.getStart());
            event.setEndTime(tmp.getEnd());
            //idd=idd+1;
            Log.d("nom",tmp.getName()+"");
            event.setColor(getResources().getColor(randcol()));
            events.add(event);
        }



        return events;
    }*/

    int randcol(){
        int[]val={
                R.color.event_color_01,
                R.color.event_color_02,
                R.color.event_color_03,
                R.color.event_color_04
        };
        int rand=new Random().nextInt(val.length);
        return val[rand];
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onEmptyViewLongPress(Calendar time) {

    }*/
}
```

and this is the class with the events called

```java
package com.example.calendar;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.alamkanak.weekview.DateTimeInterpreter;
import com.alamkanak.weekview.MonthLoader;
import com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView;
import com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekViewEvent;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WeekView.EventClickListener, MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener, WeekView.EventLongPressListener, WeekView.EmptyViewLongPressListener {
    private static final int TYPE_DAY_VIEW = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_WEEK_VIEW = 3;
    private int mWeekViewType = TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW;
    private WeekView mWeekView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);



        // Get a reference for the week view in the layout.
        mWeekView = (WeekView) findViewById(R.id.weekView);

        // Show a toast message about the touched event.
        mWeekView.setOnEventClickListener(this);

        // The week view has infinite scrolling horizontally. We have to provide the events of a
        // month every time the month changes on the week view.
        mWeekView.setMonthChangeListener(this);

        // Set long press listener for events.
        mWeekView.setEventLongPressListener(this);

        // Set long press listener for empty view
        mWeekView.setEmptyViewLongPressListener(this);

        // Set up a date time interpreter to interpret how the date and time will be formatted in
        // the week view. This is optional.
        setupDateTimeInterpreter(false);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        setupDateTimeInterpreter(id == R.id.action_week_view);

            if(id == R.id.action_today)

    {
        mWeekView.goToToday();
        return true;
    }

            if(id== R.id.action_day_view) {
                if (mWeekViewType != TYPE_DAY_VIEW) {
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    mWeekViewType = TYPE_DAY_VIEW;
                    mWeekView.setNumberOfVisibleDays(1);

                    // Lets change some dimensions to best fit the view.
                    mWeekView.setColumnGap((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setEventTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                }
                return true;
            }
            else if(id== R.id.action_three_day_view) {
                if (mWeekViewType != TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW) {
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    mWeekViewType = TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW;
                    mWeekView.setNumberOfVisibleDays(3);

                    // Lets change some dimensions to best fit the view.
                    mWeekView.setColumnGap((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setEventTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                }
                return true;
            }
           else if(id == R.id.action_week_view)
            {
                if (mWeekViewType != TYPE_WEEK_VIEW) {
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    mWeekViewType = TYPE_WEEK_VIEW;
                    mWeekView.setNumberOfVisibleDays(7);

                    // Lets change some dimensions to best fit the view.
                    mWeekView.setColumnGap((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    mWeekView.setEventTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                }
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Set up a date time interpreter which will show short date values when in week view and long
     * date values otherwise.
     *
     * @param shortDate True if the date values should be short.
     */
    private void setupDateTimeInterpreter(final boolean shortDate) {
        mWeekView.setDateTimeInterpreter(new DateTimeInterpreter() {
            @Override
            public String interpretDate(Calendar date) {
                SimpleDateFormat weekdayNameFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.FRANCE);
                String weekday = weekdayNameFormat.format(date.getTime());
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" d/M/Y", Locale.FRANCE);

                // All android api level do not have a standard way of getting the first letter of
                // the week day name. Hence we get the first char programmatically.
                // Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959502/get-one-letter-abbreviation-of-week-day-of-a-date-in-java#answer-16959657
                if (shortDate)
                    weekday = String.valueOf(weekday.charAt(0));
                return weekday.toUpperCase() + format.format(date.getTime());
            }

            @Override
            public String interpretTime(int hour) {
                return ""+hour ;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmptyViewLongPress(Calendar time) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Empty view long pressed: " + getEventTitle(time), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),addEvent.class));
        finish();
    }

    protected String getEventTitle(Calendar time) {
        return String.format("l'evenement de %02d:%02d %s/%d", time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), time.get(Calendar.MINUTE), time.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventClick(WeekViewEvent event, RectF eventRect) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "l'evenement : " + event.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventLongPress(final WeekViewEvent event, RectF eventRect) {

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Long pressed event: " + event.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder supprimer = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
        supprimer.setMessage("voulez vous supprimer cet evenement ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("confirmer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                db_cal db = new db_cal(getApplicationContext());
                Calendar b=event.getStartTime();
                Calendar e = event.getEndTime();
                String name = event.getName();
                db.supprimer(b,e,name);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = supprimer.create();
        alert.setTitle("supprimer evenement");
        alert.show();


    }



    public WeekView getWeekView() {
        return mWeekView;
    }
}
```

i would like to show these events correctly if anyone can help

Comment: Link to your library.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: thank you Bassil i'll look it up and the link is the following  https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Comment: i uderstood part of the problem is that it shows me the same event without showing the other it's like the others don't load